# Winform's OK button is never called

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Grasshopper component, which is a Rhino 3D plugin which does graphical programming. I have a code snippet from winforms, like so:

```
    public void ShowForm()
    {
        hmf.ShowDialog();

        if (hmf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

            MessageBox.Show("DialogResultOK was hit.");
            // store winforms values into global vars

            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Params.Input[0].ToString());
                Grasshopper.Kernel.Parameters.Param_String param = (Grasshopper.Kernel.Parameters.Param_String)Params.Input[0];
                param.PersistentData.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i <= x.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    param.PersistentData.Append(new GH_String(x[i]));
                }
                param.ExpireSolution(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // error message
            }
        }
        else if (hmf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DialogResultCancel was hit.");
            this.ExpireSolution(false);
        }
    }
```

It offers two conditions, a `DialogResult.OK` and `DialogResult.Cancel`. In theory, when `OK` is called, it saves the winforms values into my global variables, else it goes to `DialogResult.Cancel`.

For some reason, when I use the `MessageBox.Show("...")`, it shows that `OK` is never called.

Here is the `forms` code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // ok
    {
    }

    public Button button1Object{ get { return this.button1; } }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // cancel
    {

    }

    public Button button2Object { get { return this.button2; } }
```

This is how my `form` looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the ShowDialog() function three times!  Call it once and put its result into a variable.  Each time you call it, there's a different response.   Your approach makes your "if" statement have blocks of code that are unreachable.

```
public void ShowForm()
{
    var a = hmf.ShowDialog();

    if (a == DialogResult.OK) {

        MessageBox.Show("DialogResultOK was hit.");
        // store winforms values into global vars

        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Params.Input[0].ToString());
            Grasshopper.Kernel.Parameters.Param_String param = (Grasshopper.Kernel.Parameters.Param_String)Params.Input[0];
            param.PersistentData.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i <= x.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                param.PersistentData.Append(new GH_String(x[i]));
            }
            param.ExpireSolution(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error message
        }
    }
    else if (a == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("DialogResultCancel was hit.");
        this.ExpireSolution(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I also noticed that it took three times to close my dialog once I compiled it. You are right in that it was called three times. Let me fix this and get back to you.

Comment: Hey codenoire. It seems to have fixed my prior issue, however, clicking OK still does not save my results. For example, clicking OK does nothing. Clicking the red close button prompts me to hit `DialogResultCancel was hit` though if I open the dialog again, the results are saved o.O

Comment: Ok, now that this is fixed, examine the properties of the button on form hmf and make sure it's returning DialogResult.OK (another poster put that up, but seems to have deleted it)

Comment: Could you clarify how I could examine the properties of the button, and what you want me to find out about it?

Comment: In the winforms editor, right click the button, and select Properties.  Then you'll see something that looks like this (I just grabbed the first image url I could to demonstrate, but don't take this literally) http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC466893.png and look for the dialog result in the list at bottom right.